# Airflow simple tasks failing without logs with small parallelism LocalExecutor (was working with SequentialExecutor)

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Running airflow (v1.10.5) dag that ran fine with `SequentialExecutor` now has many (though not all) simple tasks that fail without any log information when running with `LocalExecutor` and minimal parallelism, eg.

```py
<airflow.cfg>

# overall task concurrency limit for airflow
parallelism = 8 # which is same as number of cores shown by lscpu
# max tasks per dag
dag_concurrency = 2
# max instances of a given dag that can run on airflow
max_active_runs_per_dag = 1
# max threads used per worker / core
max_threads = 2

# 40G of RAM available total
# CPUs: 8 (sockets 4, cores per socket 4)

see https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-scaling-workers/
```

Looking at the `airflow-webserver.*` logs nothing looks out of the ordinary, but looking at `airflow-scheduler.out` I see...

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ tail -n 20 airflow-scheduler.out
....
[2019-12-18 11:29:17,773] {scheduler_job.py:1283} INFO - Executor reports execution of mydag.task_level1_table1 execution_date=2019-12-18 21:21:48.424900+00:00 exited with status failed for try_number 1
[2019-12-18 11:29:17,779] {scheduler_job.py:1283} INFO - Executor reports execution of mydag.task_level1_table2 execution_date=2019-12-18 21:21:48.424900+00:00 exited with status failed for try_number 1
[2019-12-18 11:29:17,782] {scheduler_job.py:1283} INFO - Executor reports execution of mydag.task_level1_table3 execution_date=2019-12-18 21:21:48.424900+00:00 exited with status failed for try_number 1
[2019-12-18 11:29:18,833] {scheduler_job.py:832} WARNING - Set 1 task instances to state=None as their associated DagRun was not in RUNNING state
[2019-12-18 11:29:18,844] {scheduler_job.py:1283} INFO - Executor reports execution of mydag.task_level1_table4 execution_date=2019-12-18 21:21:48.424900+00:00 exited with status success for try_number 1
....
```

but not really sure what to take away from this.

Anyone know what could be going on here or how to get more helpful debugging info?

Comment: In process of debugging. This seems helpful: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#task_fails_without_emitting_logs. Need to read more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking again at my `lscpu` specs, I noticed...

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             2
```

Notice `Thread(s) per core:    1`

Looking at my `airflow.cfg` settings I see `max_threads = 2`. Setting `max_threads = 1` and restarting both the [`scheduler`](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-scaling-workers/) seems to have fixed the problem.

If anyone knows more about what exactly is going wrong under the hood (eg. why the task fails rather than just waiting for another thread to become available), would be interested to hear about it.

Comment: Ever find out more information on why it just fails with no logs?

Comment: @Benbentwo Have not, but I do think that the fact that I set the parallelism `max_threads` to a value beyond what my machine could actually support was the issue (just because that was the only thing that changed between testing). What is going on under the hood here, IDK. You could open a github issue on the CKAN repo to ask about this if wanted to.